# Initialize a static cache with command line arguments

Tags: java, caching, static

I have a class that uses a static cache that is shared between all instances of the class. I'd like to be able to set the timeout of the cache at runtime.

To provide a concrete use case: I cache values fetched from cloud storage. I'd like to refresh the values much quicker in development environments than in prod. When deploying the code, it takes an argument for the config file corresponding to that environment. This config file can contain a value for the cache refresh time.

```
public class Pipeline {
    private static final LoadingCache<BlobId, Definitions> CACHE =
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .refreshAfterWrite(VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // <-- how do I set VALUE from a config file?
                    .build(
               new CacheLoader<BlobId, Definitions>() {
                   public Definitions load(BlobId key) throws Exception {
                       return DefinitionsLoader.load(key);
                   }
               });
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically load different configurations at runtime, you can use a *.properties* file. In the example below I load the properties file in a static block, but you can also implement the logic in a static method that initializes the cache.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

```
private static final LoadingCache<BlobId, Definitions> CACHE;
static {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }

    Long value = Long.parseLong(prop.getProperty("value", "5")); 
    CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .refreshAfterWrite(value, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(new CacheLoader<Integer, Definitions>() {
                public Definitions load(BlobId key) throws Exception {
                    return DefinitionsLoader.load(key);
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static field initialized in their declaration are not designed to be parameterized as you want to do.

Besides, your cache loading is not flexible.
If tomorrow you change your mind or you want to use multiple of them, you cannot.

At last, it is not testable either.

If you want to provide a specific behavior to the cache loading, the most natural way to do it is changing the API of the class that contains the field.

You could provide a `Pipeline`  constructor with a `long delayInMnToRefresh` parameter and you could use this parameter to set the refresh time of the cache.

```
public Pipeline(int delayInMnToRefresh){
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .refreshAfterWrite(delayInMnToRefresh, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       ....
}
```

If you use Spring, your could using a `@Autowired` constructor that uses a property defined at runtime when the Spring context is loaded  :

```
@Autowired
public Pipeline(@Value("${clould.cache.delayInMnToRefresh}") int delayInMnToRefresh){

       ....
}
```

With a property defined in this way for example in env :

> clould.cache.delayInMnToRefresh=5

And another property defined in this way for example in prod :

> clould.cache.delayInMnToRefresh=15

Of course, you can implement this requirement without Spring (and Spring Boot) but you should simply perform more boiler plate tasks (load the properties file before to call this method and handle yourself the notion of environment).